# remove rows in migration rails way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I want to delete `adresses` rows that has no `street` in my migration.

I want something like this :

```
def change
  execute('DELETE FROM adressess WHERE street IS NULL;')
end
```

My question is: how can I write this migration more rails-way, so it can be reversible, and allow me to rollback this migration in the future?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the *reversible* part of migration. You can't bring back deleted data - if you remove your addresses they will not come back if you make a `down` migration - only the database-
 columns will. The function you are looking for should be in a **controller-method**, not a migration. And you should somehow save the deleted data (for example in a [before_destroy](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)), if you want to be able to bring it back later. Deleted data is deleted/gone forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've got the answer so maybe it could be helpful for someone:

`rails g migration RemoveEmptyStreetRowsFromAdress`
<-- migration

code to remove rows conditionally:

```
def change
  Adress.where(street: nil).destroy_all
end
```

or

```
def change
 Adress.where('street IS NULL').destroy_all
end
```

Comment: You don't need the ' around nil - that would look for a string - just write `nil`.